# Finding an operator C that satisfies AB=CA

Tags: fourier-transform, matrix-exponential, differential-operators, similar-matrices, sylvester-equation

Let $D=\frac{d}{dx}$ , $A=\sum_{i=-n}^{i=n} a_i(x)D^{i}$ and $B=b(x)D$, where $a_n(x)$ and $b(x)$ are sufficiently smooth functions and $n$ is an arbitrary positive integer. $A$ may not be invertible. Assume that $AB=CA$. What can be said about operator $C$? Is it possible to write $C$ as a function of $A$, $D$ and $B$?

Note that if $A$ is invertible, $C=ABA^{-1}$.

Additionally, if $A,B$ and $C$ are matrices, this problem is similar to the homogeneous [Sylvester matrix equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to rephrase the problem and add more details.

Comment: I had a couple of typos in my indicies and just corrected them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algebra of differential operators is graded by $\deg(A):=n$ for $A=\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}a_n(x)D^n$, if $a_n\not\equiv 0$. It has the property that $\deg(AB)\leq \deg(A)+\deg(B)$, and the equality holds if either $a_n$ or $b$ is not a zero divisor (otherwise it might happen that $a_n(x)b(x)=0$ for all $x\in I$, reducing the degree of $AB$).

Thus in the generality of your question we should assume that $\deg(AB)=\deg(A)+\deg(B)$. Hence the leading coefficient (w.r.t. $D^{n+1})$ of $AB$ is given by $a_n\cdot b$ and the candidate for $C$ is given by $C=bD+c$ for $b$ given and some $c$. On the other hand the lowest coefficient (w.r.t. $D^0$) of $AB$ is $0$, since $B=bD+0$, but for $CA$ it is given by $(bD+c)a_0$, which determines $c$ for most $x\in I$. Yet there are many more constraints given by the coefficients of the other degree terms.

Taking another approach one can directly show, that the equality $AB=CA$ holds for $C=B$, if $a_i,b$ are all constant, since constant functions commute with $D$.

Just another remark: If we exclude the question of the existence of an inverse of a differential operator $A$, its inverse should satisfy $\deg(A^{-1})=\deg(A)^{-1}=-n$, since $0=\deg(I)=\deg(AA^{-1})=\deg(A)+\deg(A^{-1})$ (assuming equality holds). So $A^{-1}$ wouldn't be a (classical) differential operator and neither would $C=ABA^{-1}$ be in general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understood you correctly, given the generality of the problem, we cannot find a differential operator. What if $n=\infty$? Can we obtain an operator with deg($C$)$=m$ for some $m$?

Comment: You would need to define what you mean by saying $\deg(A)=n=\infty$. Although let me mention, that there is a notion of (pseudo) differential operators $A$ with $\deg(A)=-\infty$, so called 'smoothing operators'.

Comment: By $deg(A)=n=\infty$, I mean if the operator is defined asymptotically. For instance, $e^{\frac{d}{dx}}=\sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(\frac{d}{dx})^{n}$

Comment: I see. Then one would need to define a suitable domain within a Banach space for $B=\exp(D)$ to make sense of those limits in the operator norm. Since you were mentioning $\exp(D)$: There is a general notion of the exponential $\exp(A)$ of classes of operators $A$. One needs substancial knowledge about the spectrum of $A$ to be able to define it (for instance the spectral theorem for compact or self-adjoint operators or more general some theory of sectorial operators). But these do not apply here, since $D$ has continuous spectrum $\mathbb{R}$.